# How to target to the right interpreter when downloading a large file with gdown using a poetry python project?

Tags: python, download, chmod, python-poetry

I'm using gdown for downloading a large file from Google Drive within a poetry python project. After executing `chmod +x bin/download_model` and bin/download_model, I got a `wrong interpreter: Permission denied` error. In my project root I have the folders bin and assets and within bin folder the file download_model yields with this comands:

```
#!/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my_project-67vF9gQQ-py3.9 python
import gdown

gdown.download(
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1V8itWtowCYnb2Bc9KlK9SxGff9WwmogA",
    "assets/model_state_dict.bin",
)
```

How can I target to the right interpreter, the one I'm using is the one that `poetry env info --path` command retrieves.

This is the log I got:

```
bash: bin/download_model: /home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my_project-analysis-67vF9gQQ-py3.9: wrong interpreter: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, the problem is that you didn't activated your virtual environment.

To activate it you may either connect to a new shell with working venv or activate it through your session.

1.

```
poetry shell
```

2. 

```
source /home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my_project-analysis-67vF9gQQ-py3.9/bin/activate
```

Comment: Don't forget to install your libraries in the activated venv

Comment: I have my poetry env activated and all libraries installed (included gdown), but I keeps showing `wrong interpreter: Permission denied`.

Comment: Which OS you are running it on? And pls send response from 'which python' in the terminal.